# SharePoint Link Update

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

We are migrating to the on-prem version of SharePoint 2019.  Is it possible to update the SharePoint link in the upper left corner?  It's currently linking to MySite, but our organization is not using MySite at this time.[image: SharePoint-screenshot]